# How to print a string associated with a stored int read from a txt file?

Tags: c++, string, file

I have precipitation data stored in a txt file, in the form of dates and a number for each date.  I need to find the max value of precipitation in the data, and print the date and that value.

So what I want to print is:

2/11/2018 1.18

I've managed to find and print the max value, but I'm having trouble printing the date along with it.  I've tried storing the date for that line as a unique string, and printing it, but that isn't working for some reason.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double num, maxnum = -1;
    string date, maxdate;
    ifstream precip;

    precip.open("precip.txt");

    while(precip >> date >> num)
    {
        if(num>maxnum)
        {
            maxnum = num;
            maxdate = date;
        }
    }
    cout << maxdate << " " << maxnum << endl;
 }
```

Comment: What is the format of your file? What is the output you get now?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me assuming the input has one entry per line with the date and value space separated. Please provide an example input, desired output, and actual output. "Not working" is not a problem statement.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: The file is a txt file.  The output I get is " 1.18", just a space and the max number, not the date associated with it.

Comment: Toby Speight, I am just learning c++, and this is how we've been taught so far.  I'm sure we will get into what you're saying later on.  Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I don't know why I thought this wasn't working, but it is.  I just ran it, and it works fine.  Thanks for the help.